# Is it okay to munge deployables in a single migration?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I'm hoping to use openzeppelin-solidity contracts. One of them uses Ownable. Is the following okay to do (via truffle compile and migrate)?  Thank you.

```
var OmniCAT = artifacts.require("./OmniCAT.sol");
var Ownable = artifacts.require("./Ownable.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Ownable);
  deployer.deploy(OmniCAT);
};
```

Comment: Sure, but if it's the correct way for your situation depends on whether OmniCAT inherits from Ownable. Please add your contract code if you want someone to take a look at it

Comment: You say one of them 'uses' Ownable and I think you mean it 'inherit' from Ownable. If that is the case inherited contracts should not be deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct from a `js`syntax point of view. But since the `OmniCat` uses the  `Ownable` contract, you should wait for it to deploy then deploy `OmniCat`.

This is because, deployment takes time so it is done asynchronously. truffle uses promises when deploying.

in the end I think this will work better :

```
var OmniCAT = artifacts.require("./OmniCAT.sol");
var Ownable = artifacts.require("./Ownable.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Ownable).then(
      Ownabledeployed =>{
        deployer.deploy(OmniCAT);
  });

};
```